# Unity Jenkins Android Gradle Task :mergeReleaseResources FAILED, Command line working fine

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, jenkins, gradle

I am trying to setup Jenkins server for automatic building for Unity, but I am getting gradle error.

Building using command line is working fine, but if try use Jenkins its failing.

Logs:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':mergeReleaseResources'.

  > 8 exceptions were raised by workers:
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #7: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #3: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #6: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #5: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #2: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.0-5326820-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
  >   This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
]
stdout[

> Task :preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>
> Task :preReleaseBuild
>
> Task :compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
>
> Task :compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>
> Task :checkReleaseManifest
>
> Task :generateReleaseBuildConfig
>
> Task :prepareLintJar
>
> Task :generateReleaseSources
>
> Task :javaPreCompileRelease
>
> Task :mainApkListPersistenceRelease
>
> Task :generateReleaseResValues
>
> Task :generateReleaseResources
>
> Task :mergeReleaseResources FAILED

```
8 actionable tasks: 8 executed
]
exit code: 1
  at UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) [0x00031] in <24d9b022aa584914af833273ea899103>:0 
  at UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) [0x00015] in <24d9b022aa584914af833273ea899103>:0 
  at UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) [0x0000a] in <24d9b022aa584914af833273ea899103>:0 
  at UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) [0x0001f] in <24d9b022aa584914af833273ea899103>:0 
  at UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) [0x00029] in <24d9b022aa584914af833273ea899103>:0 
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
  at UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) [0x0004d] in <24d9b022aa584914af833273ea899103>:0 
  at UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) [0x000a8] in <24d9b022aa584914af833273ea899103>:0 
  at UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) [0x00074] in <24d9b022aa584914af833273ea899103>:0 
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
  at UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex) [0x0001e] in <24d9b022aa584914af833273ea899103>:0 
  at UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) [0x00110] in <24d9b022aa584914af833273ea899103>:0 
  at UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) [0x002c8] in <24d9b022aa584914af833273ea899103>:0 
  at UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) [0x00001] in <24d9b022aa584914af833273ea899103>:0 
  at UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) [0x000da] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPipeline\PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:281 
UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildPlayerInternalNoCheck(String[], String, String, BuildTargetGroup, BuildTarget, BuildOptions, Boolean)
UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildPlayerInternal(String[], String, String, BuildTargetGroup, BuildTarget, BuildOptions) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPipeline.bindings.cs:368)
UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildPlayer(String[], String, String, BuildTargetGroup, BuildTarget, BuildOptions) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPipeline.bindings.cs:267)
UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildPlayer(BuildPlayerOptions) (at C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPipeline.bindings.cs:250)
AutomateBuildProcess:StartBuild() (at Assets\[ProjectName]\Scripts\Utility\Editor\AutomateBuildProcess.cs:35)

(Filename: <24d9b022aa584914af833273ea899103> Line: 0)
```

Building script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

public class AutomateBuildProcess
{
    private static string BuildsFolder = "D:/GDP/Jenkins/workspace/[ProjectName]/Builds/";

    public static void StartBuild()
    {

        List<string> enabledScenePathNames = new List<string>();
        foreach (var scene in EditorBuildSettings.scenes)
        {
            if (scene.enabled)
            {
                enabledScenePathNames.Add(scene.path);
            }
        }

        string buildNumber = "GradleFixTest"; //Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BUILD_NUMBER");
        string _fileName = "[ProjectName]_" + buildNumber + ".apk";

        Debug.Log("Starting android build");
        BuildPlayerOptions newBuildPlayerOptions = new BuildPlayerOptions();
        newBuildPlayerOptions.scenes = enabledScenePathNames.ToArray();
        newBuildPlayerOptions.locationPathName = BuildsFolder + _fileName;
        newBuildPlayerOptions.target = BuildTarget.Android;
        newBuildPlayerOptions.targetGroup = BuildTargetGroup.Android;
        newBuildPlayerOptions.options = BuildOptions.None;
        BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(newBuildPlayerOptions);

    }

}
```

Unity arguments for building:

```
-quit -batchMode -executeMethod AutomateBuildProcess.StartBuild -logFile D:/Editor.log
```

Jenkins is running on Windows 10 machine.

Comment: any solutions was found? same problem in my case.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows, just changed the Jenkins service's "log on as" to my account to solve this issue.

How to fix it:

1. open system service
2. find jenkins service
   [image]
3. change log on user from local system to account
   [image]

Comment: This was my issue. Only the Jenkins service itself was using the user account, but the Agent service wasn't. I changed the Agent service to run with the "this account" option and gradle started behaving.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this problem was caused by using windows user with limited privileges. Fixed by switching to admin user.